# How to (try)parse a single String to DateTime in "DD/MM/YYYY" format? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, datetime, parsing, format, tryparse

How to (try)parse a single String to DateTime in "DD/MM/YYYY" format? (VB.Net)

For example: I use input string "30/12/1999" (30 December 1999), how to (try)parse it to DateTime?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim date As Datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(_
    yourString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This will throw an exception if `yourString` does not match the format you specify.  If you do not want an exception in this case then do this:

```
Dim date As Date    
Date.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, _
                      DateTimeStyles.None, date)
```

Comment: I will handle the exception instead of TryParse.
Thank you again. Answer accepted!

Comment: Note: if you expect that the string won't always be a valid date, TryParse and TryParseExact are generally faster.  (Throwing and catching exceptions can be expensive.)  Also, they return a boolean indicating whether they could parse the date.