# Date format from database gets wrong date in vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, parsing, date

I'm taking in data from a SQL database and now I'm trying to convert the data to a proper date variable in VB.NET but I don't get the proper format.

Data from the database:

```
28-FEB-14 01:00:00:0
28-FEB-14 13:00:00:0
```

The date I get when trying to convert it:

```
2028-02-14
2028-02-14 12:00:00
```

The code that is doing the conversion:

```
    Dim theDate As DateTime
    Dim try1 As Date

    For i As Integer = 0 To batchCount - 1
        If Date.TryParse(dv(i)(0), theDate) = True Then
            try1 = theDate.ToUniversalTime()
        End If
```

Would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Try Date.ParseExact()

Have a loot at similar post [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794305/how-to-tryparse-a-single-string-to-datetime-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-vb-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, date values in your database should be date types, so when you read them in, you read them into a Date type variable.

If you then want to format that date you can use a `ToString` overload

```
Dim theDate as DateTime = dr.item("date")
Debug.Writeline(theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Secondly if the date is being stored as a string field in the database (you should not do this but you may have no control over this) it should be in a specific format, so you can use ParseExact to convert this into a date:

```
Dim dateString As String
dateString = DateTime.ParseExact(dr.item("Date"), "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.f", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm trying to parse it not but I get error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
Guessing I doing wrong on the parsing. 
28-FEB-14 01:00:00:0 = "dd-MMM-yy HH-mm:ss:f", is this not correct parsed?

Comment: Thanks again I was as I suspected my fault.
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.f"